# How to group by multiple columns in cratedb

Tags: cratedb

Can someone help me on group by multiple columns in crate?

For ex.

SELECT COUNT(1), x, y from table GROUP BY x,y

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the resultset can exceed 25000 records.  

Error!

SQLActionException[CircuitBreakingException: [query] Data too large, data for [collect: 0] would be larger than limit of [622775500/593.9mb]]

Comment: Please help me which parameter I need to increase. Where is this default configuration exists.

My Heap size is already 16G.

CRATE_MIN_MEM=256m  
CRATE_MAX_MEM=1g  
CRATE_HEAP_SIZE=16g

Answer (score 2):

Your grouping statement seems good (you should use count(*) though, CrateDB opimizes for that specifically, count(1) will be slower), but the CircuitBreakerException and the low amount of memory stated there indicates a memory misconfiguration.

Can you set

```
CRATE_MIN_MEM=16g
CRATE_MAX_MEM=16g
CRATE_HEAP_SIZE=16g
```

What operating system are you working on? `CRATE_HEAP_SIZE` should automatically set `CRATE_MIN_MEM` and `CRATE_MAX_MEM`, but there might be a problem with precedence...

Cheers, Claus